# How to filter out the lines that don't have data under them using GREP?

Tags: grep

I have data that is in the following format

```
-----------------data1-------------
that- 485
that- 234
that- 789
-----------------data2-------------
that- 343
-----------------data3-------------
this+ 123
this+ 509
this+ 837
-----------------data4-------------
that+159
-----------------data5-------------
this+151
```

How can i get only the lines that have 'this' in them along with the data line? My output should be like:

```
-----------------data3-------------
this+ 123
this+ 509
this+ 837
-----------------data5-------------
this+151
```

I've tried `grep 'data\|this'`, but this also includes the data line even if 'this' isn't present under it. Using this command the output looks like this:

```
-----------------data1-------------
-----------------data2-------------
-----------------data3-------------
this+ 123
this+ 509
this+ 837
-----------------data4-------------
-----------------data5-------------
this+151
```

Comment: Can you name a maximum number of consecutive `this` lines which you need to handle?

Comment: Not sure about the edge cases of your input format, but try to simply grep for "this" and the preceeding line: `grep -B1 this`. It seems to work for the given sample input. If that does not work please provide sample input for which this fails.

Comment: I created this account today. I can't upvote any answers as my account has less than 15 reputation points.

Comment: Read the link. Accepting one of the answers you can do. Just click one of the "tick marks" next to the answers.

Comment: Can you ever have a block that contains both `this` and that`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (for the provided sample input) that grepping for "this" and the preceeding line (option `-B1`) works:

```
grep -B1 this
```

This, as is, gets the output

```
-----------------data3-------------
this+ 123
this+ 509
this+ 837
--
-----------------data5-------------
this+151
```

If you do not like the separator line `--`, you can filter it with a second pass.

```
grep -B1 this | grep -v "^--$"
```

i.e. only keep what does not match (option `-v pattern`) the separator.
Then you get as desired:

```
-----------------data3-------------
this+ 123
this+ 509
this+ 837
-----------------data5-------------
this+151
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. But shouldn't `-B1` option cause some lines to be repeated?Lets take `data3` as an example. `this+123` is matched and the preceding line `data3` is also printed along with `this+123`. When `this+ 509` is matched, shouldn't its preceding line (`this+ 123`) also be printed, thus leading to two instances of `this+123` .

Comment: I would not say "should", maybe "could". But I agree with grep implementers that it would never be of benefit, i.e. would not match any use-case I can think of. So - it does not.

Comment: And the "--", which I intentionally remove in the second version, indicates where lines "coagulate", i.e. where additional "-B1" lines are skipped.